# HtmlUnit find the presence of a form for login

Tags: java, htmlunit

For doing web scraping I'm trying to figure out when I get a specific url if the loging form is present:

```
  if(!page.getForms().isEmpty()){
     HtmlForm loginForm = page.getFormByName("Valid");
     if(loginForm != null){
      //No valid session so login
       loginForm.getInputByName("usercode").setValueAttribute("MyUser"); 
       loginForm.getInputByName("userpwd").setValueAttribute("mypwd");
```

But this doesn't work because I got an exception when the form is not present.
Is there a way of detecting without exception the presence of the form?

Comment: What exception do you get and in which line? What value does loginForm hold when the form is not present?

Comment: In fact I got the normal exception of a non found element. So at the end I put a try catch around my code.

Comment: That makes sense. That way you can get rid of the `if` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to the comments. I close the question and stop looking for strange things to do in place of of catching the exception.